# Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm getting two errors when I try adding new data to an array with mongoose. Here is my code:

```
return await db.fileMeta.findOneAndUpdate({
    username: username,
    'files.fileUID': {
        $ne: data.fileUID
    }
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        files: data
    }
}).exec();
```

`data` is a JavaScript object with 25 items that amounts to `789` bytes... Nothing near 16MBs. My code worked fine until recently (last few days) then I started getting this error:

```
MongoError: BSONObj size: 16829075 (0x100CA93) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: $v: 1
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:719:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:298:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 10334,
  codeName: 'BSONObjectTooLarge'
}
```

Then the above error stopped and I got anther instead:

```
MongoError: Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:719:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:298:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 17419,
  codeName: 'Location17419'
}
```

Using MongoDB Compass I can see this:

[image]

Note the total size of `16.2MB`, this is the only thing that I can think of that is even lose to 16MBs.

I would understand that if the error was trying to say that my `data` object was too large, but since it is so small (`789` bytes) I don't understand why I'm getting the error or how to fix it. If the error is because the entire DB is larger than 16MBs then something must be wrong because obviously DBs should scale larger than 16MBs.

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: I think you need to make more, smaller documents rather than 1 massive one.

Comment: `789` bytes is massive?

Comment: The screenshot you shared says you have 3 documents with an average size of 5.4MB.  addToSet probably updates your document every time you call it.

Comment: @Evert ah ok I see. Each document represents a user, then they each have an array of file metadata objects that my `data` was pushing to. Switching to a more flat structure would require a lot of rebuilding, but if you think that the DB structure I have now is the problem I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I am no Mongo expert, but having everything in a few massive documents feels like the wrong design!

Comment: You're probably right. I'll comment back if the flattening worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took @Evert's advice and flattened my DB so that each file's metadata was it's own document instead of an array within a document. And now it works fine.

```
const fileMetadataDocument = new db.FileMetadata(data);

const saved = await fileMetadataDocument.save();
//Works
```